# iOS Vision: VNRecognizedText boundingBox(for:) method returning identical bounding box for any range

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, visionkit, ios-vision

I'm using the iOS Vision framework to perform OCR via a `VNRecognizeTextRequest` call, and I'm trying to locate each individual character in the resulting `VNRecognizedText` observations. However, when I call the `boundingBox(for range: Range<String.Index>)` method on any `VNRecognizedText` object and for any valid range within the recognized text, I get the same bounding box back. This bounding box corresponds to the bounding box of the entire string.

Am I misunderstanding the `boundingBox(for:)` method, or is there some other way to get discrete location info for single characters within a recognized text observation?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

After looking into this more, I've realized that there's some sort of link with word groups and whitespace.
Consider a recognized text observation with a string value of "Foo bar". Calling `boundingBox(for:)` for each character in "Foo" returns the exact same bounding box which, based on the dimensions, seems to correspond to the entire substring "Foo" instead of the single character whose range we pass into the `boundingBox` method. Then, in another bit of strange behavior, the `boundingBox` for the whitespace character is simply an empty region at the origin whose edges don't correspond with the substrings on either side of it. Finally, the behavior for the second substring is the same as the first: each character in "bar" has the same bounding box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After hours of further investigation, I decided to get in touch with Apple Developer Tech Support. Sure enough, this is a bug! When `VNRecognizeTextRequest.recognitionLevel` is set to `.accurate`, as I had, the bug manifests. When `recognitionLevel` is set to `.fast`, the results behave as expected, with discrete bounding boxes per character.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. Did the Tech Support say something about a workaround for this ? I am relying on the `.accurate` recognition level but need character specific bounding boxes. Or were you maybe able to get it to work with `.accurate` somehow ?

Comment: No workaround offered! I ended up implementing an approximation by averaging character width across the string and updating character-level bounding boxes accordingly, but obviously this is far from ideal...

Comment: resolved by now?